# Android maps application not loading (Unexpectedly stopped error)

Tags: android, debugging, maps, android-logcat

I am working on my first android project. i am doing a maos based application. Buty when I launch I am getting the following error "application stopped due unexpected error.

here is my code. if anything more is required plz do let me know I wil post them

```
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class map extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    LinearLayout linearLayout;
    MapView mapView;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    }
}
```

this is my layout xml. I have given the apikey too.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
     android:id="@+id/mapview"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:apiKey="Api key"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

this is my manifest file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="rrj.map"
      android:versionCode="1"    
      android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
        <activity android:name=".map"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
<uses-permission
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION">
    </uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

the logcat is down please do help me in pointing out the mistake. I don know how to read the logcat

```
03-11 00:47:32.856: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(3209): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    03-11 00:47:32.856: INFO/AndroidRuntime(3209): Heap size: -Xmx18m
    03-11 00:47:32.856: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(3209): CheckJNI is OFF
    03-11 00:47:32.861: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(3209): pLocation:english, pLang: en, pRegn: GB
    03-11 00:47:32.866: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(3209): setted country_code = India
    03-11 00:47:32.866: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3209): /system/csc/sales_code.dat ==> cannot open file
    03-11 00:47:32.981: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(3209): --- registering native functions ---
    03-11 00:47:33.206: DEBUG/ddm-heap(3209): Got feature list request
    03-11 00:47:33.256: INFO/WynexActivity(1981): WindowOrientationChanged: 0
    03-11 00:47:33.371: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(3209): Shutting down VM
    03-11 00:47:33.371: DEBUG/dalvikvm(3209): DestroyJavaVM waiting for non-daemon threads to exit
    03-11 00:47:33.371: DEBUG/dalvikvm(3209): DestroyJavaVM shutting VM down
    03-11 00:47:33.371: DEBUG/dalvikvm(3209): HeapWorker thread shutting down
    03-11 00:47:33.371: DEBUG/dalvikvm(3209): HeapWorker thread has shut down
    03-11 00:47:33.376: DEBUG/jdwp(3209): JDWP shutting down net...
    03-11 00:47:33.376: INFO/dalvikvm(3209): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
    03-11 00:47:33.381: DEBUG/dalvikvm(3209): VM cleaning up
    03-11 00:47:33.391: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3209): ERROR: thread attach failed
    03-11 00:47:33.391: DEBUG/dalvikvm(3209): LinearAlloc 0x0 used 663292 of 5242880 (12%)
    03-11 00:47:33.716: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(3217): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    03-11 00:47:33.716: INFO/AndroidRuntime(3217): Heap size: -Xmx18m
    03-11 00:47:33.716: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(3217): CheckJNI is OFF
    03-11 00:47:33.721: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(3217): pLocation:english, pLang: en, pRegn: GB
    03-11 00:47:33.726: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(3217): setted country_code = India
    03-11 00:47:33.726: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3217): /system/csc/sales_code.dat ==> cannot open file
    03-11 00:47:33.886: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(3217): --- registering native functions ---
    03-11 00:47:34.111: DEBUG/ddm-heap(3217): Got feature list request
    03-11 00:47:34.281: INFO/ActivityManager(1905): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=rrj.map/.map }
    03-11 00:47:34.286: DEBUG/WynexActivity(1981): ----> onSaveInstanceState()false
    03-11 00:47:34.286: DEBUG/WynexActivity(1981): ----> OnPause()false
    03-11 00:47:34.286: DEBUG/Wynex(1981): ----> OnPauseActivity()
    03-11 00:47:34.301: INFO/ActivityManager(1905): Start proc rrj.map for activity rrj.map/.map: pid=3224 uid=10058 gids={3003}
    03-11 00:47:34.326: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(3217): Shutting down VM
    03-11 00:47:34.326: DEBUG/dalvikvm(3217): DestroyJavaVM waiting for non-daemon threads to exit
    03-11 00:47:34.326: DEBUG/dalvikvm(3217): DestroyJavaVM shutting VM down
    03-11 00:47:34.326: DEBUG/dalvikvm(3217): HeapWorker thread shutting down
    03-11 00:47:34.331: DEBUG/dalvikvm(3217): HeapWorker thread has shut down
    03-11 00:47:34.331: DEBUG/jdwp(3217): JDWP shutting down net...
    03-11 00:47:34.331: INFO/dalvikvm(3217): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
    03-11 00:47:34.336: DEBUG/dalvikvm(3217): VM cleaning up
    03-11 00:47:34.351: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3217): ERROR: thread attach failed
    03-11 00:47:34.356: DEBUG/dalvikvm(3217): LinearAlloc 0x0 used 673260 of 5242880 (12%)
    03-11 00:47:34.421: DEBUG/ddm-heap(3224): Got feature list request
    03-11 00:47:34.461: DEBUG/WynexView(1981): (^^) SURFACE DESTROYED
    03-11 00:47:34.461: DEBUG/WynexView(1981): (^^) <CONSUMER>: AWKE COMSUMER THREAD TO STOP WORKING
    03-11 00:47:34.461: ERROR/WynexView(1981): (^^) <CONSUMER>: THREAD STOP
    03-11 00:47:34.471: DEBUG/WynexActivity(1981): ----> onWindowFocusChanged(false)
    03-11 00:47:34.471: DEBUG/Wynex(1981): ----> OnWindowFocusChanged()
    03-11 00:47:34.596: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(3224): Shutting down VM
    03-11 00:47:34.601: WARN/dalvikvm(3224): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b180)
    03-11 00:47:34.601: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3224): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
    03-11 00:47:34.626: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3224): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{rrj.map/rrj.map.map}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class com.google.android.maps.MapView
    03-11 00:47:34.626: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3224):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
    03-11 00:47:34.626: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3224):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
    03-11 00:47:34.626: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3224):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
    03-11 00:47:34.626: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3224):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
    03-11 00:47:34.626: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3224):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    03-11 00:47:34.626: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3224):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    03-11 00:47:34.626: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3224):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4367)
    03-11 00:47:34.626: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3224):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    03-11 00:47:34.626: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3224):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    03-11 00:47:34.626: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3224):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
    03-11 00:47:34.626: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3224):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
    03-11 00:47:34.626: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3224):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    03-11 00:47:34.626: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3224): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class com.google.android.maps.MapView
    03-11 00:47:34.626: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3224):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
    03-11 00:47:34.626: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3224):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:565)
    03-11 00:47:34.626: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3224):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
    03-11 00:47:34.626: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3224):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
    03-11 00:47:34.626: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3224):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
    03-11 00:47:34.626: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3224):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
    03-11 00:47:34.626: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3224):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
    03-11 00:47:34.626: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3224):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1622)
    03-11 00:47:34.626: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3224):     at rrj.map.map.onCreate(map.java:18)
    03-11 00:47:34.626: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3224):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    03-11 00:47:34.626: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3224):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
    03-11 00:47:34.626: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3224):     ... 11 more
    03-11 00:47:34.626: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3224): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    03-11 00:47:34.626: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3224):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:238)
    03-11 00:47:34.626: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3224):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
    03-11 00:47:34.626: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3224):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
    03-11 00:47:34.626: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3224):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
    03-11 00:47:34.626: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3224):     ... 21 more
    03-11 00:47:34.626: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3224): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MapViews can only be created inside instances of MapActivity.
    03-11 00:47:34.626: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3224):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:282)
    03-11 00:47:34.626: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3224):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:255)
    03-11 00:47:34.626: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3224):     ... 25 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What jumps out at me 1st is that map activities should extend MapActivity

Comment: On closer inspection of the error log from logcat, that does appear to be your current problem

Comment: So you'd use `public class map extends MapActivity` but I must point out that Java convention has class names starting with a capital letter

Comment: +1, here is your biggest hint `03-11 00:47:34.626: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3224): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MapViews can only be created inside instances of MapActivity.`

Answer (score 1):

Your activity must extend MapActivity and you are missing the Maps Api key in your MapView definition. You can get it [here](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html).

Comment: I have put the api key. i took it out when i posted this question

Comment: @Droidme Then you need to use MapActivity like I and the other answers said.